# SQL Remove duplicate combination

Tags: sql

If I a table:

```
  X1     X2 
  1       2 
  2       1
  3       2
```

I want to remove the duplicated pairs  regardless of whether they are in X1 or X2 and to return either

```
  X1     X2 
  1       2 
  3       2
```

or

```
  X1     X2 
  2       1
  3       2
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why you have added `mysql, sql, oracle`, I think your problem is related to a single tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have other columns and the pairs only appear once (in either direction):

```
select t.*
from t
where t.x1 <= t.x2
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.x1 > t.x2 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.x1 = t.x2 and t2.x2 = t.x1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not part of the SQL standard (which is what the `sql` tag refers to), most DBMS support the `greatest()` and `least()` functions:

```
select distinct least(x1, x2) as x1, greatest(x1,x2) as x2
from the_table;
```

Comment: Which version of sql server could support greatest() and least() Functions

Comment: @Srini131 I think SQL Server is one of the few DBMS to not support that

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name i tried in sql server i got error,thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

Always select the smallest value first. Do `UNION` to remove duplicates.

```
select x, y from table where x <= y
union
select y, x from table where x > y
```